# How do I notify a TreeModel that its underlying model has changed?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, jtree

I am developing a simulation of the world, where the `World` is represented by:

```
public class World {
    Turtle turtle;
    // .. basic constructors, getters, setters
}
```

and a `Turtle` is represented by:

```
public class Turtle {
    List<Turtle> turtles;
    // .. basic constructors, getters, setters
}
```

where a `Turtle` stands on the backs of its `turtles` and the `World` rests on one, main `Turtle` (who may have turtles underneath it). I want to represent this, in Swing, as a JTree.

So I code up a JTree and a TreeModel:

```
JTree tree = new JTree(new WorldModel(world.getTurtle());

public class WorldModel implements TreeModel {

    private Turtle = null;

    public WorldModel(Turtle turtle) {
        this.turtle = turtle;
    }

    @Override
    int getChildCount(Object object) {
        return ((Turtle) object).getNumTurtles();
    }

    @Override
    Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        return ((Turtle) object).getTurtle(index);
    }

    // etc., you get the overbearing point


}
```

This works splendidly up until the point at which I change the `Turtle` I initially passed in to the TreeModel's constructor:

```
world.getTurtle().removeAllTurtleChildren();
```

How do I update my JList to reflect this change? Do I have to create a new TreeModel and set it again?

(I would like to stay away from DefaultTreeModel, if possible.)

Comment: `TreeModel` has two important methods `addTreeModelListener` and `removeTreeModelListener`.  You need to construct appropriate events and notify any registered listeners about the change in state of the model

Comment: Fpr example, see how `DefaultTreeModel` uses `listenerList`.

Comment: why do you want to stay away from DefaultTreeModel? Any specific reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add api that supports modifying the structure to the model:

```
public class WorldModel implements TreeModel {

     ...

     public void removeAllChildren(Turtle parent) {
         if (parent.getChildCount() == 0) return;
         Turtle[] children = parent.getChildren();
         int[] locations = new int[children.length());
         for(int loc = 0; loc < locations.length; loc++) {
            locations[i] = i;
         }
         parent.removeAllChildren();
         List<Turtle> path = new ArrayList<>();
         while (parent != null) {
             path.add(0, parent);
             parent = parent.getParent();
         }

         TreeModelEvent event = new TreeModelEvent(this, path, locations, children);
         // for each listener
              listener.treeNodesRemoved(event);   
     }
}
```

As you see, it's quite some work - you might reconsider not using DefaultTreeModel :-)

Comment: That seems like a duplication of any work I'll have in my World class.

Comment: it most probably (don't see it, so just guessing) isn't - or does the world is observable?. Even if it is: there is _no_ (as in zero, zilch) way around the notification contract of a model. It simply MUST notify its observers.